# How to load multilevel relationships?

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I am trying to search in 3 related tables as follows contracts belongsTo -> companies hasMany -> company_addresses.I would like to display company_addresses data in the contracts view.

```
contracts
    id – integer
    company_id - integer
    title – string 

companies
    id - integer
    name – string

company_addresses
    id - integer
    company_id - integer
    address – string
    complement – string
    contact– string
```

Model contracts

```
public function company()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Company::class, 'company_id', 'id');
}
```

Model companies

```
public function contracts ()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Contract::class);
} 
public function addresses()
{
    return $this->hasMany(CompanyAddress::class);
}
```

Model company_addresses

```
public function company()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
}
```

Code Contract Controller

```
 public function index()
 {
     $contract= Contract::with('companies.company_addresses')->get();
     return view(‘contract.view')->with(compact('contract'));
 }
```

So what am I doing wrong and how can I fix it? Any help is very valid.

Comment: What errors are you receiving? Why do you think what you're doing is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the wrong child. Change this:

```
$contract= Contract::with('companies.company_addresses')->get();
```

to this

```
$contract= Contract::with('company.addresses')->get();
```